# How do I fix the margins on PDFs created by Sphinx easily?

Tags: django, latex, pdf-generation, python-sphinx, margins

I have a Django Project where I used Sphinx to create my documentation. I went through sphinx-apidoc and ran 'make latexpdf'. The resulting documentation has a quite a few lines that flow out of the margin. On top of margin issues, lines in the index start overflowing onto each other.

[Overflowing Lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBRc7.png)

[Margin Issues :(](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8DIS.png)

Is there an easy way to fix these issues (or an easier way to create PDF documentation)?

ELI5 if possible (I'm not well-versed in LaTeX)

Comment: Provide a reproducible example and versions of Python and Sphinx. Without that, my only suggestion is to not use a monospace font, set the monospace font to a smaller size, or use a narrower font face. In our index entries for [Pyramid PDF documentation](http://readthedocs.org/projects/pyramid/downloads/pdf/latest/), we don't use a monospace font. We used to have problems with long lines of code-block not wrapping correctly, but that seems to have been resolved in recent versions of Sphinx. Look for examples in our [source code repo](https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid/tree/master/docs).

Answer (score 2):

The overflowing lines situation in the index should improve from adding this to `conf.py`:

```
latex_elements = {
    'printindex': '\\footnotesize\\raggedright\\printindex',
}
```

Or, you can switch to Japanese language which does something like that (even better) out-of-the box from its special document class ;-)

TeX does not always know how by itself how to insert linebreaks: after all it is good at hyphenation of natural language. But as pointed out in comments Sphinx coerces LaTeX into handling better long code lines since 1.4.2.

Since recent 1.5.3, user can customize page margins, check http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/latex.html#the-sphinx-latex-style-package-options for documentation of hmargin and vmargin which can be configured via `'sphinxsetup'`.

Comment: Using 1.6.3, this suggestion greatly improved, but unfortunately did not entirely eliminate, overflowing lines from the first column into the second column of my index page. But I had some very long strings.